# I don't understand most of the solution to this recurrence relation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

https://i.postimg.cc/Mzxvbq1Y/Untitled.png

I have no idea where the fractions come from
and isn't the first line a typo?

Comment: The fractions come from the fact that $a^n=\frac{1}{a}\cdot a^{n+1}$.

Comment: There's a typo in the first line , that power $n+2$  is actually $n+1$